# Foreign key length JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name="PRIVATE_CODE_ID", nullable = false)
public PrivateCode getPrivateCode() {
    return privateCode;
}
```

I am working with a legacy MySQL database schema and want to specify the PRIVATE_CODE_ID as an int(15) rather than the default int(11).  There is no argument such as length=15 in joincolumn.  Is there a way to do this so JPA with hibernate will generate the correct schema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If you work with legacy database, you don't have to specify schema details - they are used only when JPA provider is used to generate the actual schema
2. The foreign key column definition should be consistent with primary key this foreign key points to. So start from correctly mapping `@Id` on `PrivateCode` entity.
3. There is a `columnDefinition` attribute of `@JoinColumn` annotation:

   ```
   @JoinColumn(name="PRIVATE_CODE_ID", columnDefinition="int(15)", nullable = false)
   ```